# My download speed is very slow compared to my internet speed

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a problem my internet speed is 65.0mbps and my internet net is good and fast.

However, when I download it is very slow, 500kbps, sometimes 200kbps or lower.

Do you think 500kbps is the best 65mbps can do?

How can I make it faster?

Comment: http://www.pcpro.co.uk/features/367672/whats-killing-your-wi-fi

Comment: i think it could be a server-related issue, some servers limit the download speed for clients

Answer (score 0):

if you have 65.0mbps you should be able to get that speed under best conditions, which means it can be slower due to sever problems or else.

To help us answer your question you should post your router product here or check the supportet speed of it yourself. Routers have a Max. speed, also Wlan routers could be a problem to reach Max speed.

also the wiring, but 500kbps should not be a problem there.